# How to split string from 3 dimension array to new 2 dimension array in java

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have 3-d Array and I want to split at [x][x][0] to make new array.

```
static String[][][] flight = {
      {
        {"MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN","TG2040","06:55","07:55"},
        {"MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN","TG2042","10:35","11:35"}
      },
      {
        {"MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN","TG2041","08:25","09:20"},
        {"MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN","TG2043","12:05","13:05"}
      }
```

I want to make a new 2-d array like this.

```
String[][] flight_of_day = {
{"MON","TG2040","06:55","07:55"},
{"TUE","TG2040","06:55","07:55"},
{"WED","TG2040","06:55","07:55"},
.... // Monday To Sunday of TG2040

{"MON","TG2042","10:35","11:35"},
{"TUE","TG2042","10:35","11:35"},
.... // Monday To Sunday of TG2042

{"MON","TG2041","08:25","09:20"},
{"TUE","TG2041","08:25","09:20"},
.... // Monday To Sunday of TG2041
```

Comment: Instead of using arrays (of arrays)*, define classes and use instances.

Comment: Is the 3-D Array an input you have no control over? Because like the other commenter says, classes and instances seems like a more elegant way.

Comment: i did't understand please example and explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String[][] flight_of_day =
            Stream.of(flight)
                  .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                  .flatMap(
                          t -> Arrays.stream(t[0].split(","))
                                     .map(day -> {
                                         String[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(t, t.length);
                                         tmp[0] = day;
                                         return tmp;
                                     })
                  ).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Comment: yup you are faster then me +1

Comment: Thank you very much. but are you have way to use for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

This is iterable example how to do this.

```
            final List<String[]> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[][] t : flight) {
        if (t == null) {
            continue;
        }
        for (String[] k : t) {
            if (k == null || k.length < 1 || k[0] == null) {
                continue;
            }
            for (String day : k[0].split(",")) {
                String[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(k, k.length);
                tmp[0] = day;
                tmpList.add(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    String[][] flight_of_day = tmpList.toArray(new String[tmpList.size()][]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: have error at this statement
   for(String[][] t:flight){
        if(t == null){
            continue;
        }

Comment: @PhijakChanyawiwatkul I don't see any problem in this code unless the flight is null then the method should return / throws exception:

        `if(flight == null){
            return;
        }`